# I don't understand how make task on SQL

Tags: sql

There is a table with two fields: `Id` and `Timestamp`.

`Id` is an increasing sequence. Each insertion of a new record into the table leads to the generation of `ID(n)=ID(n-1) + 1`. `Timestamp` is a timestamp that, when inserted retroactively, can take any values less than the maximum time of all previous records.

Retroactive insertion is the operation of inserting a record into a table in which

```
ID(n) > ID(n-1)
Timestamp(n) < max(timestamp(1):timestamp(n-1))
```

Example of a table:

| ID | Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2016.09.11 |
| 2 | 2016.09.12 |
| 3 | 2016.09.13 |
| 4 | 2016.09.14 |
| 5 | 2016.09.09 |
| 6 | 2016.09.12 |
| 7 | 2016.09.15 |

IDs 5 and 6 were inserted retroactively (their timestamps are lower than later records).

I need a query that will return a list of all ids that fit the definition of insertion retroactively. How can I do this?

Comment: What kind of database do you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be rephrased to :

*Find every entries for which, in the same table, there is an entry with a lesser id (a previous entry) having a greater timestamp*

It can be achieved using a `WHERE EXISTS` clause :

```
SELECT t.id, t.timestamp
FROM tbl t
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM tbl t2
  WHERE t.id > t2.id
  AND t.timestamp < t2.timestamp
);
```

[Fiddle for MySQL](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uMcQ63tMm1vfbKM9VDyaoR/0) It should work with any DBMS, since it's a standard SQL syntax.